# Custom Progress Bar for a File Download from application/octet-stream REST response

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, angularjs, rest

I have a requirement to download files to the browser by calling a REST Api which produces Application/octet-stream, the file size is around 1 GB, and I need to display a custom progress bar in the screen with percentage of download (or atleast the simple download inprogress image without any percentage).

REST api code (using jersey):

```
@Component
@Path("/DOC")
public class DownloadDOCApi {
@GET
@Path("/download")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getArticleById() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String url = "http://localhost:6060/download";
    String fileName = "fileName.msi";
    final InputStream responseStream =         client.target(url).request().get(InputStream.class);

    System.out.println(responseStream.getClass());
    StreamingOutput output = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {  
            int length;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while((length = responseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) 
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            out.flush();
            responseStream.close();
        }};   
     return Response.ok(output).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment, filename="+fileName+"").header("Content-Length","249450496").build();
}
```

URL used to invoke the REST API from front end: 
http://localhost:7070/DOC/download

I am able download the file and also I am able to get the browser's default progress bar but still I need a custom progress bar in the screen itself.

Someone help me to achieve the custom progress bar or just the inprogress image in the screen for the file download.

Comment: That would mean your javascript stuff has to be able to access the interaction with the file download. I don't think that's possible. Also that has nothing to do with the server side code you posted.

Comment: May be you have to use Real time Notification mechanism like Signal R or others to send updated response to client side to show some progress.